# How to find out the density or percentage of vegetation in each aspect

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4, aspect

I am trying to find out what is controlling vegetation in an area of Saudi Arabia for my masters project and I am currently focusing on the aspect of slopes in the area.
I have a DEM layer and I have used the aspect tool to show me which direction the slopes are facing in. I also have a shapefile feature class of points of vegetation and wish to find out the proportion/percentage or density of this vegetation in each aspect (so how much of the vegetation is only on south facing slopes etc.) but I am struggling to find a way to do this. I have tried to do it with zonal statistics but I don't know how to get it to accept the different aspects as individual zones.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the license you could use the [Extract Values to Point](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-values-to-points.htm) tool to add the aspect raster value to your point layer and then carry on with whatever method you will use to run your density analysis.

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the 'Tabulate Area', creating a cross-reference table between reclassified Aspect to 1-8 or 1-16 classes, and vegetation type areas. The resulting table would have aspect class and vegetation association. Sorry for my english.